# Difficulty Understanding Wildcards in Java

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I'm having difficulty understanding wildcards in Java generics. Specifically I have the following questions:

1. If we have a `LinkedList<?>`, why can we not add an `Object` to it? I understand that it doesn't know the type of the list, but wouldn't adding an `Object` to the list have us covered in any situation?
2. Similar to the question above, if we have `LinkedList<? extends Number>`, why can we not `add` a `Number` to it?
3. Finally, if we have `LinkedList<? super Number>`, why can we `add` an `Integer` to the list, shouldn't we only be able to add things that are a superclass of Number?

I guess I'm trying to understand how wildcards work in general, I've read the Oracle tutorials on them, and a few other things, but I don't understand why they work I suppose.

Comment: List<?> means the list may contain anything, but all of those anythings are of the same type. Since you don't know what they are, you can't add one.

Comment: For some reason I was thinking about UNIX shell wildcards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're confusing objects and types.
Unlike simple generic parameters, wildcards describe the *type* of the generic parameter.
A `List<? super Number>` isn't a list of superclasses of `Number`; it's a list of some unknown type, where that type is a superclass of number.

A `LinkedList<?>` might be a `LinkedList<Car>`.
Since an `Object` is not a `Car`, you can't add an `Object` to it.

In fact, since you don't know *anything* about what type the list contains, you can't add anything to it. (except `null`)

Similarly, a `LinkedList<? extends Number>` might be a `List<Long>`, so you can't add an `Integer` to it.  (since an `Integer` is not a `Long`)

On the other hand, a `List<? super Number>` is definitely allowed to contain `Number` or any derived class, since it can only be a list of one of `Number`'s superclasses (eg, `List<Object>`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that makes more sense to me know, but I'm still trying to understand why you can add subclasses of `Number` to a `List<? super Number>`, when we add something to a `List<? super Number>`, does it treat it as an `Object`?

Comment: It doesn't "treat it" as anything.  No matter what superclass of `Number` the list is actually _of_, it can certainly hold a `Number`.

Comment: Okay, but if you `add` an `Integer` to `List<? super Number>`, that isn't a superclass of `Number`, so how can you add it, or am I missing something?

Comment: You're still confusing objects and types.  You know that it's a `List` of some type that is a superclass of `Number`.  No matter what that type is, it can hold an `Integer`.